# Circuit construction for Destructive Swap and DIP test from the VQSD paper

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, entanglement

The paper [VQSD](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.10506.pdf)

The Destructive Swap Test computes Tr(στ ).
The Diagonalized Inner Product (DIP) Test computes Tr(Z(σ)Z(τ )) via a depth-one circuit.
Can you demonstrate how this work?

[image]